# Scale and modify image areas

Tags: c#, image-processing

I want to achieve the results as shown in this [image](http://www.mediafire.com/imageview.php?quickkey=9dg0oqva5tq8pma&thumb=4)

Scale the selected area and embed some object. Please let me know which technique is best.

Cheers

**Edit**

Comments up!

Q1:Are you trying to modify ONE image, or several?

> > Several.

Q2:What image libraries do you intend to use?

> > It is my question, which i should use.

Q3:Do you want a completely automated process, or a semi-manual is OK?

> > I shall mark the area on face to scale and then select the object of my choice from a list, one image at a time.

Q4:What parameters do you want to specify?

> > Dimensions of selected area of the face and the object to insert (like orange in this example) –

Q5:Are you aware of face recognition algorithms?

> > I believe i don't need recognition algorithms because i am selecting the area on face manually. All I need to modify the selected area as shown in the sample image. –

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scaling and modifying parts of an image.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582117/scaling-and-modifying-parts-of-an-image)

Comment: The are various good and bad techniques. However some of the good ones are better in different cases (inputs and CPU/GPU resources and run time).

Comment: @belisarius, yes it is, actually stackoverflow closed my previous question due to insufficient information. That is why i opened this new question.

Comment: Well, you are not improving much on that. Are you trying to modify ONE image, or several? What image libraries do you intend to use? Do you want a completely automated process, or a semi-manual is OK? What parameters do you want to specify? Are you aware of face recognition algorithms?

Comment: Q1:Are you trying to modify ONE image, or several?>>Several. Q2:What image libraries do you intend to use?>>It is my question, which i should use. Q3:Do you want a completely automated process, or a semi-manual is OK?>>I shall mark the area on face to scale and then select the object of my choice from a list, one image at a time. Q4:What parameters do you want to specify?>>Dimensions of selected area of the face and the object to insert (like orange in this example)

Comment: Q5:Are you aware of face recognition algorithms?>>I believe i don't need recognition algorithms because i am selecting the area on face manually. All I need to modify the selected area as shown in the sample image.

Comment: Hi "belisarius" is trying to realistically help you, pointing to the things that you might need if at all you want to achieve this programmatically ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess the obvious answer of use Adobe Photoshop is out of the question?

Comment: Yes, its a programming task, needs to do in C#.